# UserInfo passing yes click to function

Tags: java, ssh

I am using ssh tools to make a ssh connection to a school server,  the example I am using an example from the source that makes an ssh connection. My problem is I don't want any user input prompts however a prompt pops up saying the authenticity of host can't be established and the user needs to press yes to continue, how can I code it for the program to accept the prompt by itself.

```java
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
//username and host I can input directly into program so thats not a problem
// username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();

//this is the part that uses the UserInfo, which pulls up a prompt
//how can I code the prompt to automatically choose yes?    
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.setPassword("password");
session.connect();
String command = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter command", "set|grep SSH");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the code below:

```
try {
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
}
catch (JSchException e) {
    throw new TransferException("Failed to open session - " + params, e);
}

session.setPassword(password);

//  Create UserInfo instance in order to support SFTP connection to any machine 
//  without a key username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
UserInfo userInfo = new SftpUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(userInfo);

try {
    session.connect(connectTimeout);
}
catch (JSchException e) {
    throw new TransferException("Failed to connect to session - " + params, e);
}

boolean isSessionConnected = session.isConnected();
```

and most importantly:

```
/**
 * Implements UserInfo instance in order to support SFTP connection to any machine without a key.
 */
class SftpUserInfo implements UserInfo {

    String password = null;

    @Override
    public String getPassphrase() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String passwd) {
        password = passwd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String message) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yaneeve this program doesn't get rid of user prompt. When run your code I can see that user still have to click enter. Please confirm that you have put this code to say that this can be done to connect remote server, but it won't help to automate the authenticate process.

Comment: I am sorry, it has been quite a few years since I ran this code. If memory serves, we had no problems with the code and no prompt required at runtime as user input.