# JGit using SSH with Password authentification

Tags: java, git, ssh, jgit

I am using JGit in Java and have the following code:

```java
SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
  @Override
  protected void configure( Host host, Session session ) {
    session.setPassword( "password" );
  }
} );

CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();
cloneCommand.setURI( "ssh://user@example.com/repo.git" );
cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback( new TransportConfigCallback() {
  @Override
  public void configure( Transport transport ) {
    SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
    sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
  }
} );
```

I was trying to clone a repository, which is secured with SSH. 
I would like to force JGit to use my credentials, like username and password.

In my case, JGit internally checks my system environments and finding my `.ssh` folder, where the public key is stored and uses it to authenticate.

So, there is no need to use credentials like password and username. 
But, I want to force JGit to use credentials and not checking my environment variables and finding my public key.

Is there a way, to clone an ssh-repository and force JGit to use my credentials instead of the public key?

Comment: Did you try to override `JschConfigSessionFactory::configureJSch`? This will give you access to a `JSch` instance. Perhaps removing all identities with `removeAllIdentity` may lead to the desired behaviour..

Comment: Hallo @RüdigerHerrmann no, I did not try yet. 
I read your article: https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/ 
and played around, to force JGit to use my credentials .. but it was not successful. 
Maybe I really need to try it out with "removeAllIdentity".

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann if I removeAllIdentity, 
how can I pass then the "credentials"? Is it with the "CredentialsProvider"? 

Thanks

Comment: I'd think you need to add an identity that holds username and password. That's what I would try first. Maybe this will also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835756/how-do-i-authenticate-programmatically-using-jsch

Comment: When I override the createDefaultJSch(FS fs) and create an instance JSch and call the method "removeAllIdentity", 
I am getting now an Auth fail, thats, why I think I have to pass the credentials somewhere. Because I want to avoid the auth. via ssh key, instead just passing the credentials somewhere.