# JSch doesn't work on first connect session.connect()

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

When trying to use JSch to connect to remote servers I can connect to servers fine and get what I need. But every first connect to a server JSch refuses the connection and throws an exception. If I do the server that failed again it works fine, it seems to be only on first time connect when starting the application. I have compared the session from when it fails to when it works and they are both the same and just can't figure out why on earth it is failing the first time.

```
public class SSHConnector {

private static String password;

private String connectionRefused = "Connection refused to server. Server could be offline. \r\n";

/**
 * Constructor for SSHConnector
 */
public SSHConnector() {

}

/**
 * Get all versions for a server via SSH connection
 * 
 * @param hostname
 *            The hostname of the server
 * @param username
 *            The username of the server
 * @param port
 *            The port of the server
 * @param password
 *            The port of the server
 * @param location
 *            The folder location of the server
 * @return hashmap of all the versions
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getVersions(String hostname, String username, int port, String password,
    String location) {

HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

String command = "cd " + location + "; ls";

String folders = "";
folders = getFolders(command, username, hostname, port, password);

if (!folders.equals(connectionRefused)) {
    String[] foldersList = folders.split("\n");

    for (String folder : foldersList) {
    command = "cd " + location + "/" + folder + "; ls";
    result.put(folder, getFolders(command, username, hostname, port, password));
    }
} else {
    result.put("", folders);
}

return result;
}

private String getFolders(String command, String username, String hostname, int port, String password) {
String result = "";

JSch jsch = new JSch();

Session session = null;
try {
    session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
} catch (JSchException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);

UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(ui);
try {
    session.connect(); // Fails first time here
} catch (JSchException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

SSHConnector.password = password;

Channel channel = null;
try {
    channel = session.openChannel("exec");
} catch (JSchException e) {
    return connectionRefused;
}
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

channel.setInputStream(null);

((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = channel.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    channel.connect();
} catch (JSchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    try {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0) {
        break;
        }
        result = new String(tmp, 0, i);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
    try {
        if (in.available() > 0) {
        continue;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
    }
}
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();

return result;
}

/**
 * MyUserInfo class
 */
public static class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo {

/**
 * Get passphrase
 * 
 * @return null
 */
public String getPassphrase() {
    return null;
}

/**
 * Get password
 * 
 * @return password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * Prompt Password
 * 
 * @return true
 */
public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Prompt Passphrase
 * 
 * @return false
 */
public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Prompt Yes No
 * 
 * @return false
 */
public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Show Message
 */
public void showMessage(String message) {

}

}
```

}

It fails at the same part each time:

```
try {
    session.connect(); // Fails first time here
} catch (JSchException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error that I am receiving is:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:511)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at uk.co.joshuawoolley.ssc.ssh.SSHConnector.getFolders(SSHConnector.java:86)
at uk.co.joshuawoolley.ssc.ssh.SSHConnector.getVersions(SSHConnector.java:51)
at uk.co.joshuawoolley.ssc.ssh.SSHManager.queryServers(SSHManager.java:41)
at uk.co.joshuawoolley.ssc.gui.GenerateReport$5.actionPerformed(GenerateReport.java:117)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Pictures of issue:

[Picture after clicking button for first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZnNm.png)

[Picture after clicking button for second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy3eL.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell me which user authentication you are trying to do if it is password based.. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561862/userinfo-passing-yes-click-to-function

Comment: Could you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
//You should set the password before your first connect.

string SSH_PASSWORD = "your password";
session.password(SSH_PASSWORD);
```